# show alert in flash

Tags: flash

I have a simple button in flash where I have given action script

```
on (release) {
alert("Welcome!");
}
```

to show an alert message just like javascript.But it is not showing anything.Can any one tell me how to show an alert message in flash cs3?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
ExternalInterface.call("alert", "Welcome!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Its helpful tutorial
[Flash - MX 2004 - Alert Box Components](http://www.webwasp.co.uk/tutorials/c06-alerts/index.php)

hopes thats helps

Answer (score 0):

simple solution

```
on (release) {
trace("Welcome!");
}
```